# How to remove last n characters of a particular column

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file

```
had my.file
    Ha1_00044012__C 1 51035805 10.35639322
    Ha1_00045184__C 1 86676829 10.07929888
    Ha1_00045056__C 1 150178524 19.44076068
    Ha10_00000491__C 10 73473488 10.6038893
    Ha10_00000577__C 10 78976728 12.45451149
    Ha10_00002949__C 10 113658711 14.94370396
    Ha10_00001805__C 10 220068670 10.87452401
```

I want to remove the last 3 characters "__C" from the first column.
I tried

```
awk '{gsub(/[__c ]/,"",$1)}3'
```

but it removes all "_" in the column one.
my desired output should look like this:

```
head desired
Ha1_00044012 1 51035805 10.35639322
Ha1_00045184 1 86676829 10.07929888
Ha1_00045056 1 150178524 19.44076068
Ha10_00000491 10 73473488 10.6038893
Ha10_00000577 10 78976728 12.45451149
Ha10_00002949 10 113658711 14.94370396
Ha10_00001805 10 220068670 10.87452401
```

Comment: You have numerous typos in your question, e.g. `had`, should there be leading spaces in the input? Please check carefully and edit your question. Also, please show what output you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the text is rigid enough that it's merely `__C` that you want to remove you can do this quite easily using `sed` too:

```
$ sed 's/__C//' file
    Ha1_00044012 1 51035805 10.35639322
    Ha1_00045184 1 86676829 10.07929888
    Ha1_00045056 1 150178524 19.44076068
    Ha10_00000491 10 73473488 10.6038893
    Ha10_00000577 10 78976728 12.45451149
    Ha10_00002949 10 113658711 14.94370396
    Ha10_00001805 10 220068670 10.87452401
```

Further cleanup can be done with `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/__C//;s/^[ ]*//g' a
```

This would remove all the leading spaces starting at the beginning of each line, up to the `H` in `Ha1`.

Answer (score 3):

The square brackets around `[__c ]` make it into a *set* rather than a *sequence* of characters. With `gsub`, that's going to make it match (and replace) every `_`, `c` (lower case, note) and space character in `$1`

What you seem to want is to replace a single instance of the sequence `__C` (upper case) which you can do with `sub(/__C/,"",$1)`

If you need it to be case insensitive, you can use `/__[Cc]/`

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using the following way:

```
perl -lane '
  substr($F[0], -3) = ""; # remove the last 3 chars from the 1st field
  print "@F";             # print the fields, space separated
' my.file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bash-4.1$ awk -v ncr=3 '{$1=substr($1,0,length($1)-ncr)}1' test.txt
Ha1_00044012 1 51035805 10.35639322
Ha1_00045184 1 86676829 10.07929888
Ha1_00045056 1 150178524 19.44076068
Ha10_00000491 10 73473488 10.6038893
Ha10_00000577 10 78976728 12.45451149
Ha10_00002949 10 113658711 14.94370396
Ha10_00001805 10 220068670 10.87452401
```

ncr = it's variable. here you can specify how many characters you want to remove from the particular column.