# awk/sed: unable to properly remove the last 5 characters from timestamps

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression

I have a test file `barcforex.txt` with 3 lines:

```
"20200424090011.047Z","New","0232917586","USD",8393000000.0000,"EUR"
"20200424120025.308Z","New","0132910586","INR",8393000000.0000,"USD"
"20200425120025.027Z","New","0132910587","USD",110000000.0000,"INR"
```

I want to extract the first field (timestamps) and chop off the last 5 characters (from `.` to `Z`), so that the output looks like this:

```
"20200424090011"
"20200424120025"
"20200425120025"
```

I nearly succeeded with this attempt:

```
awk -F',' '{ print $1 }' barcforex.txt |  sed 's/.[0-9]Z//g'
```

which gave me this output:

```
"20200424090011.0"
"20200424120025.3"
"20200425120025.0"
```

Other attempts, like this:

```
awk -F',' '{ print $1 }' barcforex.txt |  sed 's/^.[0-9]+Z$//g'
```

and this:

```
awk -F',' '{ print $1 }' barcforex.txt |  sed 's/^.[0-9]{3}Z$//g'
```

gave the same output:

```
"20200424090011.047Z"
"20200424120025.308Z"
"20200424120025.308Z"
```

How to properly remove the last 5 characters from the timestamps?

Comment: Also see [How to remove last n characters of a particular column](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/459471/100397) which isn't quite a duplicate but is very close

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several ways; here are three

```
awk '{print substr($1,2,14)}' barcforex.txt   # Print 14 characters of string from position 2

awk -F'[".]' '{print $2}' barcforex.txt       # Split line at double quotes and dots; print 2nd field

grep -Po '(?<=^").*?(?=\.)' barcforex.txt     # RE to match between first " and first .
```

In general, if you're using `awk` you *probably* don't need `sed` (or `grep`)

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk -F'"' '{print int($2)}' file
20200424090011
20200424120025
20200425120025

$ sed 's/"\([^.]*\).*/\1/' file
20200424090011
20200424120025
20200425120025
```

Answer (score 0):

Done by below methods

command

```
awk -F "," '{print substr($1,1,15)substr($1,21,1)}' filename

sed 's/\..*/"/g' filename

python


#!/usr/bin/python
o=open('io.txt','r')
for  i in o:
    q=i.split(".")[0]
    print('{0}"'.format(q))
```

output

```
"20200424090011"
"20200424120025"
"20200425120025"
```